# Groovy - Error: Groovy: Internal groovyc error: code 1

Tags: java, groovy

Everytime I try to run a groovy script I recive the error message I mentioned above. I don't really have a clue how to handle this error, I only can give you the entire error message.

`Information:Groovyc: While compiling tut:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:400)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache.scanExtClasses(MacroMethodsCache.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache.access$000(MacroMethodsCache.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache$2.onModule(MacroMethodsCache.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModulesFrom(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache.getMacroMethodsFromClassLoader(MacroMethodsCache.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache$1.provide(MacroMethodsCache.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache$1.provide(MacroMethodsCache.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroMethodsCache.get(MacroMethodsCache.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroCallTransformingVisitor.findMacroMethods(MacroCallTransformingVisitor.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroCallTransformingVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression(MacroCallTransformingVisitor.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.MethodCallTransformation.visit(MethodCallTransformation.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:318)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:965)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:647)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:623)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:600)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:175)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.lambda$runGroovyc$0(InProcessGroovyc.java:94)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)`

I'm happy about every answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Intellij or one of its variants,
the problem of the missing dependency `javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext`
might be addressed in the article
[Groovy with Intellij](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/groovy/intellij.html).

To add the JAXB Jars:

- Open *Project Structure* dialog
- Click Modules
- Select the *Dependencies* tab and add the dependencies as shown:

[image]